# Google App Engine Login Infinite Redirect Loop in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: google-app-engine, internet-explorer-10

I have created an app with Google App Engine Java 1.8.0 with Google Apps for Business (free account) domain authentication (as in mydomain.com) and I am using the UserService to generate the loginUrl and logoutUrl.

The app checks the the UserService to see if the user is logged in and if not redirects to the generated loginUrl. The Google Apps domain login page is displayed and after the user logs in correctly, she should be logged in to the app.  This flow works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  But I get a redirect loop in IE 10. The URL flickers from:

```
https://mycustomdomainname.com/#
```

to:

```
https://mycustomdomainname.com/#/&ltmpl=ga&shdf=ChoLEgZhaG5hbWUaDlBlZXIgUmV2aWV3IFFBDBICYWgiFLbTEJDqU-HZ_rg0FT6B0Cm-Nls1KAEyFJHlcVyS-lY4ucS6BLI8PCjRHri4
```

The generated loginUrl is:

```
https://www.google.com/a/mygoogleappsforbusinessdomain.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://mycustomdomainname.com/#/&ltmpl=ga&shdf=ChoLEgZhaG5hbWUaDlBlZXIgUmV2aWV3IFFBDBICYWgiFLbTEJDqU-HZ_rg0FT6B0Cm-Nls1KAEyFJHlcVyS-lY4ucS6BLI8PCjRHri4
```

I looked around and saw similar questions but no luck.

Thanks,

Dave